# Push notifications in Edge never arrive - is it supported

Tags: push-notification, notifications, microsoft-edge, web-push

I am testing push notifications and it seems to work as expected in Chrome. However, I cannot get it to work in Edge (v110). No error messages or anything. I can subscribe and I get an endpoint that looks like https://wns2-ch1p.notify.windows.com/w/ but actual notifications never come through.

Interestingly, I can get a notification to come thru using the dev console service worker tab and the "push" option, but never automatically.

SO and the internet at large are a bit vague whether the current version of Edge actually supports it or not. Perhaps there are special conditions that must be met that Chrome does not require. MS docs imply that it is fully supported, but in the context of an installed PWA - which made no difference for me.

Does it work? Do you have it working? Or am I wasting my time.

Comment: Yes, Web Push is supported by Edge and it works. You need to check the HTTP status code returned by WNS in order to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Push Notifications is supported in Edge. For more information, please read [this doc](https://webpushdemo.azurewebsites.net/). You may need to check the tutorial to see what's missing. My first thought would be WNS failing to trigger the Push event so that you can only manually hit the "push" option in DevTools.

Comment: It's working after a restart. Not sure which, if any settings, made a difference. Even that site wasn't working for me. All's good now. Thanks for the confirmation.